# Extract ID from URL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

This is the link to writte the link in htaccess:

```
 RewriteRule ^carti-Dragoste/([a-zA-Z0-9_$\-]+)\.html$ book.php
```

This is the code to read the ID from link:

```
 $id_tot=explode("_",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);    
$id=$id_tot['1'];    
$id1=substr($id,0,strlen($id)-5);
```

And this is the query:

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM carte WHERE id=" . $id1;    
 $res=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());    
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))    
 {    
 $titlu=$row['titlu'];    
 $categorie=$row['categorie'];    
 $link=$row['link'];    
 $link2=$row['link2'];    
 $hits=$row['hits'];    
 $uploader=$row['uploader'];    
 $data_ad=$row['data_ad'];    
 $tags=$row['tags'];    
 $linkpoza=$row['linkpoza'];    
 $descriere=$row['descriere'];    
 $hits++;    
 }    
 $q="UPDATE carte SET hits='" . $hits . "' WHERE id='" . $id1 . "'";    
 mysql_query($q);
```

The link written is like this

```
    http://example.com/carti-Dragoste/ $titlu_$id.html
```

The spaces from titlu are replaced with -

I need to read only the id from the url...

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: How to extract the ID from URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work:
$tetsUrl = "http://example.com/carti-Dragoste/ $titlu_$id.html";
$idOnlyTmp = array_pop(array_reverse(explode(".", $testUrl));
$idOnly = array_pop(explode("_", $idOnlyTmp));
echo $idOnly;